# Compilation error during mvn -install

Tags: java, maven

I've tried both mvn install and mvn clean install And both of them throw out the same error:

```
[Error] *dir/class.java* try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
```

Here is the information of my environment:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_77-debug, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.77-0.b03.el6_7.x86_64-debug/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Is it because that the maven run on java 1.5 but not 1.8? If so, is there method to change the version that maven used?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Java features which are only available from a specific Java version you should declare it in your `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    ...
</properties>
```

The appropriate JDK should be in the `PATH` when you run `mvn`.

e.g.

```
JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.77-0.b03.el6_7.x86_64-debug/
export PATH=${JDK_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
mvn <your_maven_parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change java version to 1.7 or higher

You can override version in pom

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In spring-boot project you can override version in properties

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Linux. The only problem that you have is that you are using `try-with-resource` which was introduced by Java 7 and by default maven is configured to compile java source code with 1.5 spec. If you need to use `try-with-resource` feature, as @UUID specified, you can configure `maven-compiler-plugin` to compile using at source and target 1.7

> Is it because that the maven run on java 1.5 but not 1.8?

No, Maven can run on any Java version (I don't know which version of Java that Maven doesn't run). However I think the maximum version that Maven can compile depends on the Java version that the Maven is running on. I.e. if your maven runs on JDK 7, then the maximum version of source and target would be Java 7 as well.

Comment: The version of Java where Maven itself is running (Minimum 1.7 for 3.3.X) with has nothing to do which can be used for compiling / testing etc. For such purposes you can configure toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

try-with-resources  is only available from java 1.7. For that you need to use source java version to >=1.7 and target version >= 1.7 (i.e. >= $source.version)

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your java -version returned a correct Java 8 version, 
Java version: 1.8.0_77-debug, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Make sure that you have javac -version also returning correctly
Java version: 1.8.0_77-debug, vendor: Oracle Corporation.

Comment: The Maven Compiler Plugin  uses Java 1.5 as a default if not specified.